# Define An object Array In avro schema java

Tags: java, spring-boot, avro

I have a below avro schema content :

```
"fields":[
{
 "name" : "data",
 "type" :[
   "null" ,
   {
  "type":"array",
  "items":[
   "string",
   "null"
  ]
}
],
"default":null
}
```

So, this data is currently a List of Strings. So, we got a new Requirement :

We have set object of  Type, **com.test.Pos and com.test.Trans**
(basically both data of type  position/transaction  model has to get go to consumer as part of this Data field. So, that json  parsing is easy at their end]

```
**If the model was only one type, I could see we can set it as below:

"type": {"type" :"array" ,"items":"com.test.Position"}}**
```

But since, I have to set both model com.test.Pos/com.test.Trans  as part of the same data field,[for both the data we will be using same avsc file for consumer]

How can we achieve it? How should we define the avro, so that data field can accept these 2 type of object also (com.test.Pos and com.test.Trans)

Comment: You already have a union type of `string, null` for your array items; just change the union type to include the other two. Make sure `null` is first as the first type in a union is the default type.

Comment: I don't get, why you say, their JSON parsing should be easy? Aren't you using the avro serialization? And Avro doesn't have the notion of `any`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think the opener asked for `accept any kind of object.`. Never heard of such a possibility, nor does it make sense imho.

Comment: @Boris the Spider  can you show me example..I am not sure how to mention..I am very new to avro

Comment: Hi  @Christina,  yes the ask is any type of object.eg :Suppose i  define a hash Map Map<String,Object> samplemap. In this  samplemap, i can  set any type of object .similar is my requirement..

Comment: @Boris the Spider  ,are you saying to mention it like as below: "items":[
   "null","string","com.test.Pos","com.test.Trans"
  ]

Comment: Hi  @Christina,  Ask is ,how show I define my  data field in avro so that it can accept both com.test.Pos and com.test.Trans

Comment: @Boris the Spider ,are you saying to mention it like as below: "items":[ "null","string","com.test.Pos","com.test.Trans" ] ..It is telling com.test.Pos not found error while building

Comment: I thougt it is `com.test.Position` according to your above example. But it should be possible referencing the name. e.g. `{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "LongList",
  "aliases": ["LinkedLongs"],
  "fields" : [
    {"name": "value", "type": "long"},
    {"name": "next", "type": ["null", "LongList"]}
  ]
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try as follows:

```
[
{   
  "type": "record",   
  "name": "com.test.Pos",   
  "aliases": ["com.test.Position"],   
  "fields" : [     
    {"name": "value", "type": "long"}
  ] 
},
{   
  "type": "record",   
  "name": "com.test.Trans",   
  "aliases": ["com.test.Transition"],   
  "fields" : [     
    {"name": "value", "type": "int"}
  ] 
},
{   
  "type": "record",   
  "name": "data",   
  "aliases": ["com.test.Union"],   
  "fields" : [     
    {"name": "foo", "type": ["null", "string", "com.test.Trans", "com.test.Pos"]}
  ] 
}]
```

Converts to:

```
{
  "oneOf" : [ {
    "$ref" : "#/definitions/record:com.test.Pos"
  }, {
    "$ref" : "#/definitions/record:com.test.Trans"
  }, {
    "$ref" : "#/definitions/record:data"
  } ],
  "definitions" : {
    "record:com.test.Pos" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "value" ],
      "additionalProperties" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "value" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "minimum" : -9223372036854775808,
          "maximum" : 9223372036854775807
        }
      }
    },
    "record:com.test.Trans" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "value" ],
      "additionalProperties" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "value" : {
          "type" : "integer",
          "minimum" : -2147483648,
          "maximum" : 2147483647
        }
      }
    },
    "record:data" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "required" : [ "foo" ],
      "additionalProperties" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "foo" : {
          "oneOf" : [ {
            "type" : "null"
          }, {
            "type" : "string"
          }, {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/record:com.test.Trans"
          }, {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/record:com.test.Pos"
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```